# Unable to start Tridion Content Management services

Tags: publishing, infrastructure

I have been working on creating a new development VM with a Tridion 2013 installation. Everything seemed to have gone according to plan, but when I check the services I notice a number had not started despite being set to automatic start. When I try to manually start them I receive this error:

[image]

Checking the Windows error log, I see an error corresponding to each attempt to start one of these failed services with the message:

[image: Logs error general]

Unfortunately, the details tab provides no additional information:[image: Log error details]

Does anyone have a suggestion for getting these services to start?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is with the Java Development Kit installation.

Looking back at the prerequisites for the Tridion 2013 I decided to check the Java installation. Even though I had just done a fresh installation of Java, when I tried `java -version` in a command prompt I received the error message

> Error occurred during initialization of VM.
>   java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object.

Using the advice of this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11008750/jre-throwing-noclassdeffounderror-error I uninstalled my Java and reinstalled it. Once this was done I was able to start all of my services and Tridion began to function correctly.

Answer (score 3):

Glad that the issue has already been resolved, however, I have experienced this issue quite a number of time (> 10) and below were few reasons of this issue:

- The password of the MTS User or the user with which Tridion services are configured to run has expired
- The JRE/JDK installation has got corrupted due to automatic update or may be a wrong update done by the IT department

The biggest challenge is that generally nothing get logged into the event logs and it makes diagnosis quite a difficult task.

Comment: The second point is an important one. You should *never* have Java configured to automatically update on a Tridion server. Many of us have this habit from the old days when you had to deploy jars into the endorsed directory, (which would be replaced by an update), but it's just as relevant now, considering how often an update is broken.

Comment: Absolutely agreed Dominic and I had a very tough time explaining this to clients which generally have their global IT policies and are reluctant to make an amend in that. I have even seen funny IT policies where they want to keep their Service user like MTS User password to get expired after a certain period and always kept all automatic update of all installation.

I Also agree with your point like we need to re-consider old fashioned policies considering how often update like JRE/JDK fails